# How to make a msi installer for installing a IE ActiveX control using flexera installshield?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, installshield, installshield-2012

I have an Active X control which i would like to install in several windows machines .
I read some articles which said it would be possible by writing an msi installer .

I am familiar with Flexera installshield and have made basic msi installers but i have no idea how to go about this .. :(

I just want to place the dll in a path and register it .. how should this be done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a component and add the file to it.  Mark it as the keyfile and then right click extract COM.  InstallShield will virtualize the registration process and extract the results into your MSI source code so that DllRegisterServer doesn't have to be called during the installation.

Build and test on a VM.

Comment: I ve tried it and it worked thanks a lot .. I also tried enabling Self Register in the dll properties after adding the file and this worked too . Is there any difference between the two methods ? or which one would you use if it were u ?

Comment: Self Registration is not a best practice. Windows Installer is a declarative, transactional installer framework.  It works best when you teach it the COM signatures and allow MSI to handle the details.  When you use SelfReg you are going behind it's back and injecting out of process code that could fail and MSI can't manage or rollback the data.